# WGL - ChoosePixelFormat and sRGB framebuffer

Tags: opengl, srgb, wgl

I have a legacy OpenGL application which sets a pixel format based of `ChoosePixelFormat` instead of `wglChoosePixelFormatARB` or `wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB/wglGetPixelFormatAttribfvARB`. `ChoosePixelFormat` doesn't allow to set a framebuffer color space explicitly using `WGL_EXT_colorspace` Despite that I have noticed that calling `glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRB)` provides a color space conversion when render a test texture. How does it work ? Does `ChoosePixelFormat` sets sRGB colorspace by default ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already answered your own question:

> `ChoosePixelFormat` doesn't allow to set a framebuffer color space explicitly.

There is nothing in the rules for `ChoosePixelFormat` which *forbids* an implementation to return a pixel format which supports sRGB encoding. But it is also not *required*. You can't rely on anything here. But on a modern windows using a compositor ("Aero" or whatever microsoft likes to call it), you typically will see sRGB support, but still there is no guarantee.